# Безопасность от xss

Tags: javascript, xss

Здравствуйте, есть сайт  где я могу добавлять свои свообщения, и вот пишу я
`<script>alert('xss')</script>` и начинаю просматривать и выскакивает сообщение xss в алерт окошке, как обезопасится от этого? Текстовый редактор markitup.

Comment: Ещё можно заблочить переменные

Comment: Обычно выводить правильно надо... Хотя если тут richtext editor то проблема может быть в нём. Хотя по описанию не похоже.

Comment: вырезать`script`, используя `strip_tags()`, при сохранении? часть проблемы решит.

Answer (score 2):

Не пропускать HTML. Вообще.

Markitup — достаточно абстрактный редактор. Используйте его с, например, Textile или Markdown и на серверной стороне (см. опцию `previewParserPath`) не пропускайте никакого inline HTML. Скажем, у [PHP Markdown](http://michelf.com/projects/php-markdown/) это делается опциями `no_markup` и `no_entities` (как — не помню, PHP уже много лет в руки не брал), у [Python'овского Markdown](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Markdown) — опцией `safe_mode` и т. д.

Comment: Так себе ответ. В чём тогда смысл использовать rich-редактор, если разметка запрещена?

Answer (score 0):

Используйте библиотеку для санитизации html. Например, `purify-html`.